# Common attribute not showing in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am not getting common attribute.

I have set target to SDK 33 but it doesn't work with me. I have also deleted Android API 33 and set Android 12.0(S) but a new error comes ( minCompileSdk (33) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata )

please help me

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the library versions.
An easy fix to this is setting the compile SDK version to 33.
Look at the git history to check which dependency values have changed (especially kotlin core and lifecycle)